# How to load .pem key in vertx mongo client?

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I am building a micro service in `Java` using `vert.x` and I want to write to `MongoDB` using the given mongo client [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/).

My mongoDB instance is configured with SSL. Using the native mongo driver from mongo I could have set the .pem file in the driver configuration and access my db. I couldn't find any way to insert my .pem file key to the vertx mongo driver though.
How can I access my db then?